# ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows -

Tags: oracle

I am not sure wat is wrong with the below code, I keep getting ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows.Appreciate the help.

```
Procedure SignLetter(vletterid in number,vrtype  in number,vtitle in varchar,
 vclose in number,vuserid in number, vmodifyby in varchar2,Error out varchar)
is
vsigntype number(1);

begin

  insert into letterempinfo (id, letterid, empid,
   title, usertabid, modifyby)
  values ( s_letterempinfo.nextval,vletterid,vuserid,
   vtitle,vuserid,vmodifyby );

  if vrtype =1 then --preparer

    update letterheader
    set prepareid=vuserid,
     preparedate=sysdate,
     updatedate=sysdate,
     usertabid=vuserid,
     modifyby=vmodifyby
    where id=vletterid;

    if vclose =2 then

      update letterheader
      set letterstatusid=3,
       updatedate=sysdate,
       usertabid=vuserid,
       modifyby=vmodifyby
      where id=vletterid;

      vsigntype:=2;

    else

      vsigntype:=1;

    end if;

  elsif vrtype =2 then --preparer

    update letterheader
    set reviewerid=vuserid,
     reviewdate=sysdate,
     updatedate=sysdate,
     usertabid=vuserid,
     modifyby=vmodifyby
    where id=vletterid;

    update letterheader
    set letterstatusid=3,
     updatedate=sysdate,
     usertabid=vuserid,
     modifyby=vmodifyby
    where id=vletterid;

    vsigntype:=2;

  end if;

  PACKNOTIFICATION.SendLetterEmail(vletterid,vsigntype,Error);


exception when others then

  Error:=SQLERRM;

end;
```

Comment: Well, what line is the error on.  Please show complete stack trace and input parameters.  We are not mind readers.  Nothing in these update statement would cause the error, so it is probably in PACKNOTIFICATION.SendLetterEmail()

Comment: Also, there is nothing in the code that you've posted that would seem to throw that error.  That implies that it may be coming from your `SendLetterEmail` procedure or that it may be coming from a trigger on the table/ view that you're updating.  I'd strongly suggest removing the exception handler entirely (and doing the same with any other code that is doing the same thing).  It makes no sense to catch an exception, discard all the stack trace information, and return the raw error message as an `out` parameter hoping that the caller checks the parameter.  Just let the exception propagate.

Comment: `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sqlerrm||chr(10)||dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace)` Add this to your outer `EXCEPTION` block or better wherever possible `EXCEPTION` handling , and it prints out the stacktrace upto two levels of execution call. Thus would help you to trace the origin of the exception , even the line number of the procedure!